# How to access the inner container inside the Scroller?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a container

```
<s:Group visible="true" x="100" y="0" width="582" height="300" 
    id="debugGroup" name="debugGroupName" >
        <comps:circle id="rect2" />
        <s:Rect width="100" height="100">
            <s:fill><s:SolidColor /></s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
```

So far I accessed it from my other class like this:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.debugGroup.addElement(comp_green_new_component);
```

I wanted to scroll my debugGroup container so I added a Scroller.

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%" id="scrollerDebug">
    <s:Group visible="true" x="100" y="0" width="582" height="300" 
    id="debugGroup" name="debugGroupName" >
        <comps:circle id="rect1" />
        <comps:circle id="rect2" />
        <s:Rect width="100" height="100">
            <s:fill><s:SolidColor /></s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
</s:Scroller
```

Now I can't access my debugGroup from my other class like this:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.scrollerDebug.debugGroup.addElement(comp_green);
```

Why is this? 
How to access correctly my inner container debugGroup from actionscript?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give the full path to the element, if you have its id

So replace

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.scrollerDebug.debugGroup.addElement(comp_green);
```

with

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.debugGroup.addElement(comp_green);
```